# How do I download a sound I just create with Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

There are several libraries for manipulating and playing sounds with the Web Audio API. Once I've played or manipulated a sound, though, how do I export/save/download that song?

For example, if I'm using the Howler.js library, I can play a sound with the following code. How could I download the sound to the browser?

Comment: You can create a `Blob` of the audio and use `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a `Blob URL` from the `Blob`, then download the `Blob URL`

Answer (score 1):

Want to have some Code?:

```
rec.stop();
rec.exportWAV(function(blob) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var hf = document.createElement('a');
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
  hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
  li.appendChild(hf);
  var recordingslist = document.getElementById("recordlist");
  recordingslist.appendChild(li);
});
```